# Очистка оперативной памяти и краш программы

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Вот исключение, которое обрабатываю я лично, и на нем именно крашит.

```
[09:23:30] [Exception] ScriptDomain DoTick: System.AccessViolationException: Попытка чтения или записи в защищенную память. Это часто свидетельствует о том, что другая память повреждена.
   в nativeCall()
   в GTA.Native.NativeTask.Run()
   в GTA.ScriptDomain.DoTick()
```

Журнал событий Windows говорит об этом:

```
Имя сбойного приложения: GTA5.exe, версия: 1.0.1180.2, метка времени: 0x599d9281
Имя сбойного модуля: clr.dll, версия: 4.7.2115.0, метка времени: 0x59af8ce5
Код исключения: 0xc00000fd
Смещение ошибки: 0x00000000005dafec
Идентификатор сбойного процесса: 0x390c
Время запуска сбойного приложения: 0x01d345797a2dad56
Путь сбойного приложения: E:\SteamGame\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\GTA5.exe
Путь сбойного модуля: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Идентификатор отчета: d026056f-edc2-4ab7-b36b-0ca32f58b29f
Полное имя сбойного пакета: 
Код приложения, связанного со сбойным пакетом:
```

Время от времени ловлю это исключение и краш не происходит.

```
>> EXCEPTION OCCURED AT 15.10.2017 9:17:19 FROM CLIENTSIDE SCRIPT ERROR
System.ObjectDisposedException: Доступ к ликвидированному объекту невозможен.
Имя объекта: "Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.V8ScriptEngine".
   в Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.V8ScriptEngine.VerifyNotDisposed()
   в Microsoft.ClearScript.V8.V8ScriptEngine.Execute(String documentName, String code, Boolean evaluate, Boolean discard)
   в GTANetwork.GUI.BrowserJavascriptCallback.<>c__DisplayClass4_1.<call>b__0()
   в GTANetwork.Javascript.JavascriptHook.OnTick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Как бы мне чистить память самостоятельно?

Версия .Net - *4.6.2.*

Comment: Вы обрабатываете исключение — значит, это ваша программа? Если да, у вас где-то осталась ссылка на умерший объект, и вы по ней с этим объектом работаете. Расследуйте!

Comment: @VladD, что значит умерший объект ?

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk: Ну, объект, который реализует `IDisposable`, и у которого уже был вызван `Dispose`. Судя по всему, у ТС этот объект `V8ScriptEngine`.